# How can I save the random output to use it in another function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am new to python3 I am trying very hard to add the output of the function, is there any way that I can save an output of an random integer
so that i can altogether add it please help me.

```
def dice():
    import random
    rollball = int(random.uniform(1, 6))
    return (rollball)

def dice2():
    import random
    rollball = int(random.uniform(1, 6))
    return (rollball)

print(dice())
input("you have 10 chances left")
print(dice2())
input("you have 9 chances left")
print(dice() + dice2())
#i want to print this last function but by adding only this first and second nothing else
```

Comment: You save the result from the function the same way that you save anything else: by assigning it to a variable.

Comment: can you please please elaborate or correct the code sir

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right place for a language tutorial.

Comment: ok sir how can i assign a variable to random thing

Comment: Well, see where your code says `rollball = int(random.uniform(1, 6))`? That is assigning the result from the `int` function to your variable named `rollball`. So really, you already know how to do this. Functions you write yourself work the same way as functions that are provided to you.

Comment: thanks you very much sir

Comment: Try starting smaller; I would advise seeking out some resources to help you get started with the basics. https://docs.python.org/3/ https://realpython.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable or set a global variable for it

```
import random
def dice():
    rollball = int(random.uniform(1, 6))
    return (rollball)

def dice2():
    rollball = int(random.uniform(1, 6))
    return (rollball)

roll1 = dice()
print(roll1)
input("you have 10 chances left")
roll2 = dice2()
print(roll2)
input("you have 9 chances left")
print(roll1 + roll2)
#i want to print this last function
```

### Or

use

```
import random
roll1 = 0
roll2 = 0
def dice():
    global roll1
    rollball = int(random.uniform(1, 6))
    roll1 = rollball
    return (rollball)

def dice2():
    global roll2
    rollball = int(random.uniform(1, 6))
    roll2 = rollball
    return (rollball)

print(dice())
input("you have 10 chances left")
print(dice2())
input("you have 9 chances left")
print(roll1 + roll2)
#i want to print this last function
```

Answer (score 0):

This should provide you with a basic example. I would spend some time searching out some resources to help you get started with the basics of python programming; There are an enumerable amount. You'll find it much easier to progress if you understand how to do the little things first.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9
"""
Basic Function Usage
"""
from random import uniform
from typing import NoReturn


def dice() -> int:
    """A dice function
    
    Returns:
        (int)
    """
    return int(uniform(1, 6))


def dice2() -> int:
    """Another dice function

    Returns:
        (int)
    """
    return int(uniform(1, 6))


def main() -> NoReturn:
    """ Main

    Returns:
        (NoReturn)"""
    d = dice()
    d2 = dice2()

    print('Dice: ', d)
    print('Dice2:', d2)
    print(f'Dice Total: {d + d2}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as excp:
        from sys import exc_info
        from traceback import print_exception

        print_exception(*exc_info())
```

Output:

```
Dice:  1
Dice2: 3
Dice Total: 4
```

Some possibly helpful resources:

[Real Python - Defining Your Own Python Function](https://realpython.com/defining-your-own-python-function/)

[Real Python - f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

[Official Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/)